# Field Update Javascript

Tags: javascript

When the menu is selected from the radio buttons, and the amount of guests, the total price should be updated. But couldn't find the issue in the code. It is not updating.

When menu is clicked AND Amount of guests => Total Price update.

```js
var proceed = 0;
var myTea = "";
var chosenTea;


function getSelectedText(selectList) {
  return selectList.options[selectList.selectedIndex].text;
}

function getRadioValue(radioArray) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < radioArray.length; i++) {
    if (radioArray[i].checked)
      return radioArray[i].value;
  }
  return "";
}

function getSelectedValue(selectList) {
  return selectList[selectList.selectedIndex].value;
}

function view(form) {
  var termsconds = form.terms.value;
  var tea = getRadioValue(form.teaChoice);
  var nb_people = getSelectedText(form.size);
  var multiplier = parseInt(getSelectedValue(form.size));
  var allergies = form.allergies.value;
  var champagne = form.champ.value;
  var champText = "";
  var special;
  if (champagne = true) {
    special = 10;
    champText = "with champagne";
  } else {
    special = 0;
    champText = "";
  }
  var teaprice;
  if (tea !== null) {
    teaprice = parseInt(tea)
  } else {
    teaprice = 0;
  }
  var totalprice;
  var additional;
  var totalOrder;

  totalprice = (teaprice + special) * multiplier;
  if (allergies !== null) {
    additional = "allergies to: " + allergies;
  } else {
    additional = " no food allergy ";
  }
  form.price.value = totalprice;
  if (proceed === 1) {
    if (termsconds === false) {
      alert("you must read the terms and conditions");
    } else {
      if (myTea === null) {
        alert("You must choose tea before you can proceed with order");
        proceed = 0;
      } else {
        totalOrder = "you have ordered a " + chosenTea + champText + "for " + nb_people + " and we have" +
          "noted that you have " + additional + ".\nYour toal bill is \u00A3" + totalprice + ".\n";
        confirm(totalOrder);
        proceed = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

function displayTea(teaName) {
  myTea = document.getElementById("chosenTea");
  myTea.value = teaName;
  chosenTea = teaName;
}
```

```css
body {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "corsoiva", serif;
  color: #005080;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#myTable {
  background-color: #50a0d0;
}

.myBlue {
  color: #005080;
}

.myWhite {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.toRight {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>Welcome to Web Tech's Afternoon tea</h1>
  <form>
    <table border="5" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5" id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
          <h2>Please chosse from the menu below <br> and select the number of people </h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="myWhite">
          <span class="myBlue">Please select your menu:</span><br>
          <input type="radio" name="teaChoice" value="20" onclick="displayTea('Easter AFternoon Tea');view(this.form)">
          <input type="radio" name="teaChoice" value="30" onclick="displayTea('Pastries and specialist');view(this.form)">
          <input type="radio" name="teaChoice" value="15" onclick="displayTea('Traditional Afternoon Tea');view(this.form)">
          <br>
          <span class="myBlue">Your tea: </span>
          <input type="text" id="chosenTea" size="50">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <div align="left">Please select party size and champagne option: <br><br>

            <select name="size" onclick="view(this.form)">
                        <option value="1">1 guest </option>
                    <option value="2">2 guest </option>
                    <option value="3">3 guest </option>
                    <option value="4">4 guest </option>
                     </select>

            <input type="checkbox" name="champ" value="champagne" onclick="view(this.form)">with champagne</div>
          <div class="toRight">Please enter food allergies in the input field below: <br>
            <input type="text" name="allergies" size="60"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Total price:$</b><input type="text" name="price" size="4"></td>

        <td rowspan="2" align="center"><br><br>
          <input type="button" name="proceedOrder" value="Proceed with order" onclick="view(this.form);return view(this.form)">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="terms " value="read"> I have read and accepted the <a href="Terms.html">terms and
                conditions</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </form>
</center>
```

Comment: please create a working copy

Comment: I clicked  `<>` to create a snippet and a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space in your HTML at `name="terms "`: remove it. Then `form.terms` will be valid in your code.

You could have spotted this if you would have checked the console for errors, as in your current version the following line:

```
var termsconds = form.terms.value;
```

... produces:

> form.terms is undefined